# get hash without committing

Tags: git

I need to track data being created by an application, such that the data has an identifier written alongside it, that tells the code version of the software that wrote it.

For this to work also in a development environment, it is clear that a git commit would not be made on every experimental change to the software, but rather *after data has already been created by the changed software*.

So is there a way to get a hash of the code, without a commit?

Squashing and rebasing [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095773/how-to-use-git-to-sync-code-without-committing) seem like a lot of potential for manual error, and thus seem inadequate.

I can take my own hash as a task during compilation, but the benefit of using git is that `.gitignore` already describes all that needs to be excluded from factoring into a hash of any kind; it describes the boundaries of the project quite safely. Further to that, if the project is committed after data had been created, the git hash from before the commit will still work in those cases where no additional code change will have been made.

Is there an orderly way to get a git hash of a project, or something similarly useful, without a commit?

Comment: The Linux kernel versions modules using the commit-id, and appends `-dirty` if the working tree has uncommitted changes. Depending on your needs, that might be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

> So is there a way to get a hash of the code, without a commit?

No, because the time of the commit is part of the hash.

Comment: Sure, refined to "or something equivalently useful" to the question phrasing... anything like a temporary commit that can be automatically applied as a task during every compilation, or whatever comes to mind..

Comment: Well if you're happy to do a commit then do that, and then you have a commit ID. As the comment above suggests, you can append something to the hash to indicate uncommitted changes.

Comment: That sounds too coarse grained, but waiting for clarification above about how `-dirty` is used there. Lets see what else comes up

Answer (score 2):

We use `git describe --always --dirty` for this purpose. If the working tree contains uncommitted changes it will append "-dirty". If the current commit has an annotated tag that will be used instead of the hash.

In general our build scripts (Makefiles) generate a `version.h` that has this information in it. The `version.h` is in the `.gitignore` and never committed.

Answer (score 1):

As Jonathan pointed, you need info like the time of get the commit hash.

However, you could always do this to get a sample commit hash:

Add all your files :
    `git add .`

Make a commit :
    `git commit`

Do whatever book-keeping stuff you want to do with the commit hash :

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

Get rid of the commit as if it never existed :

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

So you're back in the original place before the `git add`. This would probably be the cleanest and best way to do it. And you also now have an approximate commit hash.

Comment: Thanks, how is this hash an "approximate"? care to clarify?

Comment: The commit has is approximate as in the content that it was committing over is exactly what any other commit made on this content would give. I don't know what all factors are contained in the commit hash, but I'm sure it is impossible to replicate them.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. For what you've got staged it's

```
git write-tree
```

which spits the hash of the currently-indexed content and structure, no timestamps or message dependencies at all.

For an already-committed tree it's

```
git rev-parse $commit^{tree}
```

edit: To directly retrieve the state as of a tree id, do

```
git read-tree -um HEAD $treeid
```

and you can hunt up commits of that content using

```
git log --all --pretty=format:"%T Commit %H %d %S" \
| grep "^$treeid"
```

Comment: Is there later any way to correlate back the spit hash saved with the data, to the state of the source code at that time, if I later commit after the data has been written with this temporary hash?

Comment: Oddly enough I modify my source code and `write-tree` still spits out the exact same hash as before. Looks like it doesn't factor the content into the hash then....

Comment: re the later correlation, yes, the hash `git write-tree` spits is what a later `git rev-parse $commit^{tree}` shows.  There's nothing temporary about a hash code, it's entirely determined by the data and for cryptographic hashes it's absolute-as-absolute-gets-ly unique.

Comment: re changes not showing up: the hash is of the currently-indexed content and structure, you have to `git add` it, which puts it in the repository and updates the index entry to point to that.

Comment: This works nicely. Wonder if I should be concerned of accumulating too many trees created with `git write-tree`, if this happens automatically on each run of my project. I am not that strong on git internals I guess....

Comment: git garbage-collects the db periodically and what gets pushed/fetched is only what's needed to complete the histories being transferred, so long-term there's no worries at all.  If you're doing this so frequently that the temporary content you accumulate over the course of a month or so is eating capacity you need for other things there's lots of options, I'd suggest detailing the situation in a separate question. btw, would you mind accepting the answer? The page is a bit misleading as it stands now.

Comment: on further consideration, I am yet undecided on whether having to stage  defeats the original purpose or not. As it means a manual operation ― the staging ― is necessary for having the project state accounted for by the hash.

Comment: if only a tree could be retrieved, which includes changes not staged for commit. Git already knows about them as in `git status`